# React js Combining 2 arrays to make a new array of objects using spread and state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm new in react and js and I'm attempting to create an array from a declared array of json objects and a second array from user inputs. The idea is I have a list of objects existing, and the user can add to this list as many items as they like.

My problem is I can only currently add one more item to my list, and subsequent items over write it. I believe my issue lies in the line:

```
let newBooks = [{title, author, rating}]
```

but I'm having trouble correcting it.

```
 const addBookToList = () => {
    let newBooks = [{title, author, rating}]
    const allBooks = [...FAVOURITE_BOOKS, ...newBooks]
    setBooks(allBooks)

    setTitle("")
    setAuthor("")
    setRating("")
  }
```

For reference, everything I'm working on is within index.js

Comment: Where are `title, author, rating` coming from, and where is `FAVOURITE_BOOKS` stored? Are they all in state?

Comment: i updated the question for clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep the objects in current state as well, probably like

```
const App = () => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState(FAVORITE_BOOKS);

  const addBook = () => {
    const newBook = ...
    // append
    setBooks(b => [...b, newBook];
  };
};
```

Comment: Can you explain this concept to me a little bit? It did fix my solution, but I don't understand it. Cheers thank you for answering so quickly as well

Comment: Andy's answer has a good explanation. Basically, you are just trying to append a single element onto a list that already exists. In JS there's a standard way to write that: `const newList = [...oldList, newElement]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [updater function](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state) which "takes the pending state and calculates the next state from it". Here `prev` is the pending state, and we spread that out into a new array, and add the new book to it.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example({ favouriteBooks }) {

  const [title, setTitle] = useState('My book');
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState('Mr. Smith');
  const [rating, setRating] = useState(2);
 
  const [books, setBooks] = useState(favouriteBooks);

  function addBookToList() {
    const book = { title, author, rating };
    setBooks(prev => [ ...prev, book ]);
  }

  useEffect(() => console.log(books), [books]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addBookToList}>
        Add book to list
      </button>
    </div>
  );

}

const favouriteBooks=[{title:"Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone",author:"J.K. Rowling",rating:9},{title:"The Great Gatsby",author:"F. Scott Fitzgerald",rating:8}];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example favouriteBooks={favouriteBooks} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```